# Response object attribute coming undefined for angular rest call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to get attribute of reponse object but its coming "undefined"

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
        console.log('aaaa');
        $http.get("http://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key=569b1af&api_secret=d0de241&number=918650298011&brand=MyApp").success(function(response) {$scope.res = response.data;});
        console.log(res.request_id);
        console.log(res.status);
        console.log(res.error_text);

    };


});
```

Output on web console:

```
aaaa
angular.min.js:102 ReferenceError: res is not defined
```

Any idea what is incorrect in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `console.log` statements are outside the `$http` callback (and are running before your request is complete - also, you have no variable named `res` - you have `$scope.res`).

```
$http.get("http://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key=56a9b1af&api_secret=d30de241&number=919650298011&brand=MyApp").success(function(response) {
    $scope.res = response.data;
    console.log($scope.res.request_id);
    console.log($scope.res.status);
    console.log($scope.res.error_text);
});
```

Comment: Hi tymeJV, Thank you for your suggestion. Now error has removed but on console its blank. Its not writing any thing on console. Can you help me to figure out  this ?

Comment: Your http request is probably failing. Open your network tab and watch the status of the request

Comment: request call is happening becuase i m getting verification code on modile. but is this error failing response object ??? Error 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key=56a9b1a&api_secret=d3de241&number=9197650298011&brand=stayuncle. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.