# ReferenceError: res is not defined

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, angular7

Im  new to Angular and i'm working on Angular 7 application.When i try to retrieve data form  service ,i 'm getting this error "ReferenceError: res is not defined" inside the res object .

```
this.http.get(environment.apiURL + '/Item').subscribe((res : Item[])=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.itemList = res;
```

Service is a WebAPI service and when i manually paste the API URL in browser im getting data

Comment: just try(res : any)

Comment: I tried it ,still having the same issue ,Thanks

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz example? What's the result of the webApi? is a JSON or is text?

Comment: It's a json when  look at network tab data is there

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check below example:

> [Response object attribute coming undefined for angular rest call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415524/response-object-attribute-coming-undefined-for-angular-rest-call)

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the api url created before sending the get request?

```
const url  = environment.apiURL + '/Item';
console.log(url)

this.http.get(url).subscribe((res : Item[])=>{
  console.log(res);
  this.itemList = res;
})
```